# Materialized view in Oracle that updates real time or fast - how to?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

Suppose I have something like:

```
create table tmp_master (
    id int not null primary key,
    pid int not null,
    title varchar(32) not null
);

create table tmp_detail (
    id int not null primary key,
    mid int not null references tmp_master (id),
    category varchar(8) not null,
    intvalue int
);

insert into tmp_master values (1, 99, 'Item 1');
insert into tmp_master values (2, 99, 'Item 2');
insert into tmp_master values (3, 99, 'Item N');

insert into tmp_detail values (1, 1, 'Cat1', 1);
insert into tmp_detail values (2, 1, 'Cat1', 2);
insert into tmp_detail values (3, 1, 'Cat2', 3);
insert into tmp_detail values (4, 1, 'Cat2', 4);
insert into tmp_detail values (5, 1, 'Cat3', 5);
insert into tmp_detail values (6, 1, 'Cat3', 6);

insert into tmp_detail values (7, 2, 'Cat1', 7);
insert into tmp_detail values (8, 2, 'Cat1', 8);
insert into tmp_detail values (9, 2, 'Cat2', 9);
insert into tmp_detail values (10, 2, 'Cat2', 10);
insert into tmp_detail values (11, 2, 'Cat3', 11);
insert into tmp_detail values (12, 2, 'Cat3', 12);

insert into tmp_detail values (13, 3, 'Cat1', 13);
insert into tmp_detail values (14, 3, 'Cat1', 14);
insert into tmp_detail values (15, 3, 'Cat2', 15);
insert into tmp_detail values (16, 3, 'Cat2', 16);
insert into tmp_detail values (17, 3, 'Cat3', 17);
insert into tmp_detail values (18, 3, 'Cat3', 18);
```

I'd like to have a materialized view based on this query (or something giving the same result):

```
select id, pid, maxc1, maxc2, maxc3 from (
    select m.id, m.pid, d.category, d.intvalue from tmp_master m, tmp_detail d where d.mid = m.id
) pivot (
    max(intvalue) for category in ('Cat1' maxc1, 'Cat2' maxc2, 'Cat3' maxc3)
);
```

Result being (max values per category in details per master row, looks correct):

```
id  pid maxc1 maxc2 maxc3
-------------------------
 2   99     8    10    12
 3   99    14    16    18
 1   99     2     4     6
```

So something like this would be needed:

```
create materialized view tmp_max_ints ... as
select id, pid, maxc1, maxc2, maxc3 from (
    select m.id, m.pid, d.category, d.intvalue from tmp_master m, tmp_detail d where d.mid = m.id
) pivot (
    max(intvalue) for category in ('Cat1' maxc1, 'Cat2' maxc2, 'Cat3' maxc3)
);
```

However, it always fails on something depending on the options I give in place of ... above. MV Logs I have tried a couple of ways as well.

What kind of MV Logs and Create MV options should I use to make the MV work and update automatically as base tables change? I'm running out of ideas (nor am I much of a db expert either).

Version is Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production. Is this even possible with SE? If not, workarounds?

Comment: Pretty sure no materialized views in SE2 - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-AB56CEE3-955E-4E56-8B44-6075E889C283

Comment: Looks like standard edition 2 has triggers. Maybe you could write some clever code to keep a table called tmp_max_ints updated as your data changes...

Comment: OK so REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT is not supported by the SE. REFRESH ON DEMAND seems to be working, so I guess I need to schedule a job to run execute DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('tmp_max_ints'); every 15-30 minutes or so?

Comment: The list of [Restrictions on Fast Refresh](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/basic-materialized-views.html#GUID-505C24CF-5D56-4820-88AA-2221410950E7) is quite long. See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220263/create-a-materialized-view-on-commit-with-pivot-function

Comment: Just couldn't make it work and therefore implemented workaround based on table, stored procedure and scheduled job. Job -> Procedure(merge new and changed since last run) -> Table. Thanks for the help.